# Export torch model to onnx

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, torchvision

I am trying to convert a model.pt file to a onnx file in pytorch. When I run the code below I get a warning saying

```
no signature found for <torch.ScriptMethod object> Skipping _decide_input_format
```

What is the problem?  `torch.jit.trace()` was used before the model was saved to `model.pt` file.

Here's how the model.pt file was created:

```
script_model = torch.jit.trace(some_model, example_input)
script_model.save("model.pt")



example_input = torch.rand(1,3,125,125)

m= torch.load("model.pt")

torch.onnx.export(m, example_input,"model_onnx.onnx",opset_version=12)
```